# Android: Proper threading for ListActivity

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, progressdialog

So, I have my onCreate method here for populating a `ListView` with user installed apps. This takes a long time to do and I was trying to figure out where to make a new thread to do some of the heavy work so I can display a `ProgressDialog` while the list is loading. Here is the code I have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Find out which prefs to update
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null){
        buttonPressed = extras.getString("buttonPressed");
        loadNumber = extras.getString("loads");
    } 

    buttonPressedAppName = buttonPressed + "AppName" + loadNumber;
    buttonPressedAppPack = buttonPressed + "AppPack" + loadNumber;
    humanNamePrefs = buttonPressed + "AppText" + loadNumber;

    // Get shared preferences
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

    // Do in another thread to not slow the UI down...eventually
    adapter = createAdapter();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public ListAdapter createAdapter() {
    namesArray = new String[] { "Loading" };
    names = new ArrayList<String>();

    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    appList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

    // Now, appList contains all of the ResolveInfo stuff

    for (int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) {          
        names.add(appList.get(i).loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }

    namesArray = maker(names);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesArray);
    setListAdapter(adapter);        
    return adapter;
}
```

I had a thread handling the sorting of the list and such, but the `ProgressDialog` I had wouldn't even show up until the list was completely populated, which kind of defeats the purpose of having a `ProgressDialog`.

My question in a nutshell is where should I put this thread to use to show the `ProgressDialog` WHILE the list is finishing populating?

ANSWERED BELOW

@Femi provided an excellent tutorial on `AsyncTask` and I have my `ProgressDialog` twirling during loading of the list of apps. Thanks!

Link: http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/

Comment: have you looked at using an asynctask?  show progress before executing, then dismiss it in onPostExecute

Comment: Check this tutorial to see a working implementation. http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-progress-dialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way is to use an AsyncTask:

1. Show the progress dialog.
2. Start the async task and build the `names` ArrayList in the `doInBackground` method.
3. Pass the array list to the `createAdapter` method in the `postExecute`, and then close the progress dialog.

Comment: Ok, I put some Log commmands in there and I have found out that it's the Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm)); call that is taking so long, so I guess I need to do this in the doInBackground method. I am having issues with the generics in ASyncTask. What would be the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by generics in AsyncTask, but my goto example for the AsyncTask is http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/: it comes with a fully working example that you can modify to suit. Take a look and see if that doesn't help resolve your issues. If it doesn't post some code with the bits that aren't working and we can see where you're stuck.

Comment: Your example in the link was exactly what I needed. Thanks dude!